# What would be the correct way to use the keyword USING in the following C# code?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, using, webrequest

I'm trying to get this correct as I feel I'm missing something. I want to use the keyword `using` whenever I have an `IDisposable` object. Please note that the code works, I just want to optimize it.

I have two questions here:

1) For this code:

`HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);`

What does it mean to add `(HttpWebRequest)` like that? Am I converting `WebRequest` to `HttpWebRequest`?

Why can't I do this?

```
HttpWebRequest rq = new HttpWebRequest();
rq.Create(url);
```

2) In the functional code below, how would I go about using the keyword `using` where applicable?

```
public static int UploadFileToixLibrary(string url, string file)
{
    NetworkCredential credentials = new NetworkCredential();
    credentials.UserName = AppVars.Username;
    credentials.Password = AppVars.Password;

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url); 

    request.Credentials = credentials;
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "image/tiff";
    request.Headers.Add("X-Object-Key", Path.GetFileName(file));

    byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
    Stream st = null;

    try
    { 
        request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;   
        st = request.GetRequestStream();
        st.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);         
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        return 1;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (st != null)
        {
            st.Close();
        }
    }

    try
    {
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        response.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question 1:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
```

The reason for the cast, is that the static [`Create`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw00b1dc.aspx) method on `WebRequest` returns an instance of `WebRequest` which is most appropriate for the scheme you supply in the url (ie, http:// address will return an `HttpWebRequest`, ftp:// will return `FtpWebRequest` etc). As you know your url is http, you know you'll get back an `HttpWebRequest`, so you can explicitly cast to the right type to get access to the extra functionality `HttpWebRequest` over the abstract `WebRequest`.

Now, `WebRequest` is not `IDisposable`, so you cannot use it inside a using statement!

Question 2: In your functional code, the only place you could use a `using` statement is around the `Stream` access:

```
try
{ 
    request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;   
    st = request.GetRequestStream();
    st.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);         
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    return 1;
}
finally
{
    if (st != null)
    {
        st.Close();
    }
}
```

Could be re-written:

```
request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;   
using(var st = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    st.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);         
    st.Close();
}
```

Comment: couldn't I use USING with webresponse as well??

Comment: As a side-note, the `WebRequest.Create()` method is basically an example of the Factory Pattern.

Comment: @Testifier - Yes, anywhere where you're accessing a `Stream` you should dispose of it after, so the response is another place you should add `using` - however youre example does nothing whatsoever with the response.

Answer (score 1):

1. `WebRequest` is a abstract class, it does not expose most of the properties/methods that you're going to use. You must cast it to the appropriate type to use it. The static method `Create` will return the specialized `WebRequest` object according to your URL. As you know that this URL uses the HTTP protocol (`http://`), it's safe to cast it to `HttpWebRequest`. It could, however, be a `FtpWebRequest`.
2. You can put the `GetRequestStream` initilization inside `using(...)` statements. Looks like `WebRequest` (and its children) does not implement `IDisposable`

Comment: @DavidM I said that **I'm not sure**. However, I would have nested `using` blocks, but I would like your ideas about it

Comment: There is no problem I can see with nested `using` blocks. I was asking why you weren't sure...

Comment: @DavidM It's just because I never saw it =) funny that I gave the same answer as the correct one and didn't get even one upvote

Comment: There you go - you have now... :)

Answer (score 0):

1.
The `Webrequest.Create` method returns a `WebRequest` reference, but the actual object has different types depending on what kind of request you want to do. In your case you are doing a HTTP request, so the actual object is an `HttpWebRequest` object. You cast the reference to the actual type of the object to get access to the members that are specific for the `HttpWebRequest` class.

2.
The `HttpWebRequest` is not disposable. Use a `using` block for the `HttpWebResponse` object:

```
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: neither are `IDisposable`! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.aspx

Comment: @Jamiec: I already corrected that for the `HttpWebRequest` object. The `HttpWebResponse` object is disposable: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net.HttpWebResponse.aspx

Comment: You're totally right... its an explicit implementation so I missed it! My bad :)